# Unable to cast object of type System.Int32 to type System.String in Windosws forms c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, casting, tabs

This exception appears :
Unable to cast object of type System.Int32 to type System.String
This is the code:

```
 private void frmPractica21_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                conexion.Open();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }

            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("Select * from TablaPractica21", conexion);
            SqlDataReader lector;

            lector = comando.ExecuteReader();
            while (lector.Read())
                dgvDatos.Rows.Add(lector.GetString(0),
                lector.GetString(1), lector.GetString(0));//It appears on this line

            conexion.Close();

        }
```

`

I tried to fill a table in DataGridView from SQL, but I get this exception when I run the app, what am I missing here?

Comment: You should consider using DataTable‘s load method which will handle the datatypes for you - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.load?view=net-6.0#system-data-datatable-load(system-data-idatareader)

Answer (score 0):

To convert from int to string

```
lector.GetInt32(0).ToString()
```